# AngularJS: Resolve in RouteProvider - detecting Success / Failure?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have got a resolve working on my routeprovider but I just return the promise so i don't know if its success or failure. This is what I have

```
.when('/items', {
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
    controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        resolvedData: function(Restangular) {
            return Restangular.one('Items').get();
        }
    }
})
```

Now this does work but how do I detect success or failure. I could enter this in the resolve method, but what would I return in the success and failure. Remembering I need to have the item injected in my controller.

```
.when('/items', {
    templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
    controller: 'ItemsCtrl',
    resolve: {
        resolvedData: function(Restangular) {
            Restangular.one('Items').get().then(function(data) {
                // success
            }, function() {
                // failure
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I did see an example here but I am confused if this is what I need and how to use it?

[AngularJS - rejected $http promise with $routeProvider:resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987341/angularjs-rejected-http-promise-with-routeproviderresolve)

It seems to be returning a manual promise.

```
resolve: {
    response: ['Warranty'
        '$q',
        function(Warranty, $q) {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            Warranty.sendRequest().then(function(result) {
                dfd.resolve({
                    success: true,
                    result: result
                });
            }, function(error) {
                dfd.resolve({
                    success: false,
                    reason: error
                });
            });
            return dfd.promise;
        }
    ]
}
```

What I really want to do is in my controller have the resolved variable injected into the controller, if it fails then I would also like to have access to the failure in the controller so I can display to the user that it wasn't possible to render due to an issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just return the return value of the `then` method:

```
resolve: {
    resolvedData: function(Restangular){
        return Restangular.one('Items').get().then(function (data) {
            ...
            return successData; // resolvedData will be resolved with the successData
            }, function () {
            ...
            return failureData; // resolvedData will be resolved with the failureData
            });
    }
}
```

The `then` method [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q):

> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback or errorCallback.

Comment: Ah thats great, and in my controller how would I identify if the value I am injecting is the success or failure ??

Comment: Return an object such as {success: true, data: ...}

Answer (score 3):

If the resolve function fail, you will probably want to display to the user something accordingly (like an error message). 
It would be better to let your resolve function return a promise (without `then`) and use the internal event `$routeChangeError`.

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function() {
    // what you want to do if an error occurs 
    // ex: $rootScope.displayErrorMessage = true
  });
```

])

It will also be easier to deal with generic error (like network error / server down etc).